# By submitting forms billing and shipping, return message "Telephone this required field"

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-account, shipping-address, form-validation

When I fill out the form and send to customer base, magento returns the message `Telephone is a required field`

I've tried removing the validation of the phone field in HTML, JS and Databases, yet still blocking me the customer base.

It sends the value of the completed field, but still returns a message that is a required field

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this error persists when you fill out all the fields in your form including telephone?

Comment: Yes this error persists :/

Comment: I thought your "celular" field was conflicting with default Telephone field, but seems not if whole completed form is throwing error too. Is there any chance you are using any extension or custom override for customer data or onepage checkout?

Comment: It can be a aternativa but managed to solve by changing the database , the question was that the websites that suggest a solution point to a Telephone attribute, but the table has two eav_attribute Telephone records before was just changing the record with id = 34 changing is_required the value to 0 , bad when selected all records on this table I noticed another Telephone with is_required = 1 , when changed this allowed me to checkout .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove validation for telephone number. You need to do three things.

**Step 1:**

> remove client side validation for telephone input field.(remove validation class) In following files

```
checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checkout/onepage/billing.phtml      persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

**Step 2:**
Need to remove validation from code side.
`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php`

Copy this file to local

`app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php`

Then find a line

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {

    $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the telephone number.'));

}
```

Comment the above lines to remove the validation from code side

**Step 3:**
Need to remove validation value from DB. For that follow @saravanvelu answer.

[**Refer this**](http://swarminglabs.com/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be due to that the telephone is the required field in `eav_attribute` table.

Try this,

To change the required field value ,

```
//31 is telephone's attribute id in eav_attribute table
//2 is entity_type_id for customer/address in eav_entity_type table

UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required`= 0 WHERE `attribute_id` = 31 and `entity_type_id` = 2
```

To remove validation rules for telephone field,

```
 UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET `validate_rules`= null WHERE `attribute_id` = 31
```

Comment: He keeps returning the error message , the form sends the field value but does **not accept**!